# Should yum package be removed before installing from source

Tags: centos, yum

I previously installed git version 1.8.3.1 on Centos7 using yum.  I now want a newer version of git.  Need the yum package be first removed?

Comment: Consider finding (or creating) a package with the version you want.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  Yes, I will be creating the package I want from source.  The question is whether I should first execute `sudo yum remove git` before doing so.

Comment: The package you create will replace it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  Thanks. Last one.  I already removed git via yum.  Any need to reinstall via yum?  I planned on locating it at `/usr/local`.

Comment: I thought you were creating a package. Why are you putting the package contents in `/usr/local`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  Because I am following https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-git-on-centos-7.  I did so, however, it did not install in `/usr/local` but `/usr/local/bin` which seems better.  It isn't, however, available to my normal user account for some odd reason as I see it has `-rwxr-xr-x` permissions.  Ah, nevermind.  Forgot to log out and back in.

Comment: None of what that article says involves creating a package.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  Agree.  Sorry, meant installing from source.  My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no - you can prevent your package from being "upgraded" by *inhibiting* that in [`yum.conf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/yum.conf.5.html):

> **exclude** List of packages to exclude from all repositories, so
>                 yum works as if that package was never in the repositories.
>                 This should be a space separated list.  This is commonly used
>                 so a package isn't upgraded or installed accidentally, but can
>                 be used to remove packages in any way that "yum list" will
>                 show packages.  Shell globs using wildcards (eg. * and ?) are
>                 allowed.

Even with a custom package, you'd still want to keep yum around for other package changes.

As for the **git** package, if you had not uninstalled it, then yum would be confused about what could be done with the package, e.g., installing *compatible* packages.  Since it is gone, yum will not make assumptions about what you are installing from source.

If you're compiling from source however, it's worth a try to see if you can construct a package using whatever ".spec" file is bundled.  If it works readily, that's a plus (but don't waste time if not: many developers don't bother with compatibility concerns).

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  Are you saying I should still keep the yum version of git around (and if so, why?), or just keep yum around?  I will definitely use yum for other packages.  If I kept both the yum version of git plus installed by source version, will it cause complications determining which will be used?

Comment: As your question was worded, you were asking if you needed **yum** :-)

Comment: If you've uninstalled git, and inhibited it in yum.conf, then at worst, yum will tell you that it's unable to install something which depended on git (but that's likely only a related package such as gitk).